# Modifying node and edge properties in d3.js

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I am using d3.js to lay out a node and link graph using force layout. Nodes are represented by circles; links by lines. Under certain circumstances, I would like to change the visual characteristics (e.g., color, size, opacity, etc.) of a line or a node to denote some state change on the graph. I have been able to do that by redrawing the graph, but that jiggles all the nodes, resulting in confusing rather than clarity.

Code to create the graph:

```
force = d3.layout.force()
        .charge(-120)
        .gravity(0.2)
        .linkDistance(30)
        .size([width-pad, height-pad]);


nodeSet = svg.selectAll(".qNode");
// BIND NODE DATA
nodeSet = nodeSet.data(chartData.nodes);
// CREATE NODES
nodeSet.enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "qNode")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.size();})
    .style('stroke-opacity', function(d) { return d.opacity(); })
    .style('stroke', function(d) { return d.color(); })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(1); });
//similarly for links.

force.nodes(chartData.nodes).links(chartData.links).start();
```

To update the graph, I use this fragment:

```
    // SELECT NODES
    nodeSet = svg.selectAll('.qNode');
    // JOIN NODES
    nodeSet = nodeSet.data(force.nodes());
    // UPDATE NODES
    nodeSet.attr("class", "qNode")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.size();})
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(1); })
    .style('stroke', function(d) { return d.color(); })
    .style('stroke-opacity', function(d) { return d.opacity(); })
    .style('opacity', 1)
    .call(force.drag);
    // CREATE NODES
    nodeSet.enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "qNode")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.size();})
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(1); })
    .call(force.drag);
    // DELETE NODES
    nodeSet.exit().remove();


    // START SHOW
    force.start();
```

When this runs, the entire graph jiggles a bit before then new stroke attributes are applied.

So I have two questions: Assuming a state change in the data object will return different values for `d.size()`, `d.color()`, etc.,

1. How do I modify the visual appearance of the graph without jiggling any nodes?
2. If I do want to jiggle the nodes, can I determine which set of nodes to jiggle? (So that I can signal to the user which linkor node had their visual appearance change.)

**EDITED**

I've given up on jiggling the nodes for the time being, but the following code (based on suggestions by [@defenestrated](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2079141/defenestrated)), seems to do the trick to update the properties of some nodes and edges in the graph:

```
var allLinks = ... // my links from a d3 selectAll
var allNodes = ... // my nodes from a d3 selectAll
force = ... // my d3 force layout
function updateGraph(graph, nodeSubset, linkSubset) {
    for (var i=0; i<allLlinks.length; i++)
        allLinks[i].selected = false;
    for (var i=0; i<allNodes.length; i++)
        allNodes[i].selected = false;
    for (var i=0; i<linkSubset.length; i++)
        linkSubset[i].selected = true;
    for (var i=0; i<nodeSubset.length; i++)
         nodeSubset[i].selected = true;

    // these functions modify the selected nodes and links
    linkSubset.call(setLinkAttributes);
    nodeSubset.call(setNodeAttributes);

    if (force.alpha() == 0) {
        force.start();
        force.stop();
    }
}

function setLinkAttributes(links) {
    link.style(...);
}

function setNodeAttributes(nodes) {
    nodes.style(...);
}
```

I don't need to call `start`/`stop` or `resume` if the graph is still moving (if `alpha() > 0`) after applying attributes because the subsequent ticks pick up the new attributes. If the graph has settled, calling start refreshes it without moving the nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. have you tried calling `force.stop()` before the "update nodes" block, and `force.resume()` after?
2. you could class them based on their state - so you'd apply an `.attr("id", "changed")` to the nodes that are updating, and then use that in a d3 selection, eg. changedNodes = `d3.select("#changed")`

Comment: How can I know which nodes to modify (I would probably use a `class` attribute rather than `id`) to make the subsequent `.select()` call work? I am assuming that I have some data bound to some SVG elements; the data changes... how do I know which elements to modify?

Comment: i was just saying `id` beacuse you've already got a `qNode` class that i didn't want to mess up... and what if you set some arbitrary attribute on the data when it changes - so wherever you change or update the data, add something like this: `nodes.forEach(function(d, i) { d.changed = true });` - then i think you can make your selection later by doing a regular `.select` call with a selector function: `nodes.select(function(d,i) { return d.changed == true ? this : null }` - see [this](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-filter) for more info on filtering

Comment: Thanks for the answer to question #1: calling `force.start(); force.stop();` updated the appearance correctly. As to tweaking the nodes that have changed, that didn't work: when I restricted the set of nodes and edges to the selected set, they got moved to the middle of the chart, ignoring other nodes. I guess I might be able to fix the entire set of nodes and then just heat up the ones I want to highlight, but that seems overly complicated. I think I need a better solution.

Comment: what if you use the entire selection but filter your movement based on the `d.changed` variable, which is tied to the node? i dunno how you're jiggling nodes but the way i do it is by changing the `x` and having them jump back to a static `x0` (or `y` and `y0`). it'd look something like `nodes.attr("x", function(d) { return d.changed == true ? x+(Math.random()*10-5) : x });` and then the same thing for y. take a look at my source code for [this](http://www.samgalison.com/_new/main.html) if the wiggling is confusing.

Comment: oh, you'd also have to then call `force.resume()` after you change the `x` and `y` attr's

Comment: I expanded the question with an implementation similar to what I did to solve the update part of my question. Jiggling is still not satisfactory.

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle or something similar with the full code? it's a little hard to provide suggestions without knowing what the force layout looks like (for example). One quick thing, though - you can simplify all those `for` loops by doing `AllLinks.forEach(function (d) { d.selected = false });`